# Passing multiple values to PowerShell script from text file

Tags: powershell, range, text-files, ip-address, firewall

I'm quite new to PowerShell, so please don't blame me, I'm in complete darkness...
I have a text file containing hundreds of IP ranges.
What I want to achieve is to create a firewall rule which should block all outbound connections to these IP ranges.

I want one single firewall rule, having all IP ranges under "Remote IP-Address -> This range" in the firewall rule.

The following script works, but it has created 500 firewall rules, one for each IP range. I want to have all IP ranges in one single rule.

What command should I use instead of `New-NetFirewallRule`?

```
$Contents = Get-Content "C:\Temp\fb.txt"
foreach($Line in $Contents) {
    New-NetFirewallRule -DisplayName "Block FB" -Direction Outbound -LocalPort Any -Protocol TCP -action Block -RemoteAddress $Line
}
```

I also tried `Set-NetFirewallRule`, but all it does is replacing the IP Range, instead of adding a new range.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/netsecurity/new-netfirewallrule?view=win10-ps), RemoteAddress accepts an array of strings as input (Indicated by the [] in [-RemoteAddress <String[]>]).

Does this work for what you need?
Unrelated to your problem - I splatted the parameters since they were mostly offscreen for me.

```
$FirewallParams = @{
    DisplayName = 'Block FB'
    Direction = 'Outbound'
    LocalPort = 'Any'
    Protocol = 'TCP'
    Action = 'Block'
    RemoteAddress = (Get-Content 'C:\Temp\fb.txt')
}

New-NetFirewallRule @FirewallParams
```

Comment: Nice. If you mark as answered it should drop lower on the queue for other people to answer.